# Why doesn't work ADate between @Startdate and @Enddate?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT @Amount = SUM(T.Amount) FROM (
    SELECT 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT SUM(X.Price) 
            FROM X
            WHERE X.ID = Y.XID OR X.ID = Z.XID
            AND (X.ADate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        ) AS Amount
    FROM B
        LEFT  JOIN Y ON B.YId = Y.Id
        LEFT  JOIN Z ON B.ZId = Z.Id 
    WHERE B.Id = @Id
        AND (B.YId = @YId OR @YId < 0)
        AND (B.ZId = @ZId OR @ZId < 0)) AS T
```

And which start and end date I choose. The result is the same.

By example a start date 1/1/2012 and a end date 1/31/2012 
and then a selection of a start date 1/1/2014 and a end date 1/31/2014

by the following data: Price 500 and a ADate = 1/24/2012

Both results are 500?!

What do I wrong?

I've tried to: 
AND (X.ADate BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATETIME))

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping is good. The problem was => ( and ) was missing. 
Solvation: `WHERE (X.ID = Y.XID OR X.ID = Z.XID)`

Comment: This question can be closed.